# IIS redirect inserting double forward slash

Tags: .net, redirect, iis, web-config, http-redirect

Can't seem to work out why the following is resulting in a double slash being added:

```
<rule name="GenericRemoveDotASPX" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*).aspx(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"  />
</rule>
```

Using the above rule if I enter (the first part is {R:1} www.blah.com/blah and the 2nd part is {R:2} /blah):

```
www.blah.com/blah.aspx/blah
```

the browser is redirected to:

```
www.blah.com/blah//blah
```

However if I enter:

```
www.blah.com/blah.aspxblah
```

the browser is redirected to:

```
www.blah.com/blahblah
```

How can I stop this duplicate forward slash from being present in the redirect?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue was only present when run locally in Visual Studio 2017.

When installed on a test and production server the double forward slash was not present... how bizarre.